# How can I put the attributes in the same order in the API by using Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, api, rest, sequelize.js, backend

I am trying to put the attributes in the same order in the API by using Sequelize . How can I do that? Here is my controller function and here is my GET/API result:

---------CONTROLLER FUNCTION --------

```
bookList (req,res){
        const {page , size } = req.query
        return Book
        .findAll({
          attributes:['id',"book"],
          include: [{
            model: Author,
            as: 'author',
            attributes:['author']
          },{
            model: Category,
            as: 'category',
            attributes:['category']
          },{
            model: Publisher,
            as: 'publisher',
            attributes:['publisher']
          }],
           limit: size,
           offset: size * page
        })

        .then((result) => res.status(200).send(result))
        .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
      }
```

---------API RESULT-------------

```
[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "book": "Şehir-Kültür-İstanbul",
        "author": {
            "author": "İlber Ortaylı"
        },
        "category": {
            "category": "Hukuk"
        },
        "publisher": {
            "publisher": "Doğan Yayınları"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "book": "Kürk Mantolu Madonna",
        "author": {
            "author": "Sabahattin Ali"
        },
        "category": {
            "category": "Psikoloji"
        },
        "publisher": {
            "publisher": "Timaş Yayınları"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "book": "Mahur Beste",
        "author": {
            "author": "Sabahattin Ali"
        },
        "category": {
            "category": "Edebiyat"
        },
        "publisher": {
            "publisher": "Timaş Yayınları"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "book": "Aydaki Kadın",
        "author": {
            "author": "Sabahattin Ali"
        },
        "category": {
            "category": "Psikoloji"
        },
        "publisher": {
            "publisher": "Timaş Yayınları"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "book": "Başlangıç",
        "author": {
            "author": "Dan Brown"
        },
        "category": {
            "category": "Edebiyat"
        },
        "publisher": {
            "publisher": "Altın Kitaplar"
        }
    }
]
```

I want to put the attributes in the same order in the API. Like this:

```
{
        "id": 6,
        "book": "Şehir-Kültür-İstanbul",
        "author": "İlber Ortaylı" ,
        "category": "Hukuk",
        "publisher":"Doğan Yayınları"
        }
```

Comment: You can do it moving associated model attributes to the root level's `attributes` option

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it for you

```
bookList (req,res){
        const {page , size } = req.query
        return Book
        .findAll({
          attributes: [
            ['id', 'book', 'author', 'category', 'publisher'],
            [sequelize.col('author.author'), 'author'],
            [sequelize.col('category.category'), 'category'],
            [sequelize.col('publisher.publisher'), 'publisher']
          ],
          include: [{
            model: Author,
            as: 'author',
            attributes:['author']
          },{
            model: Category,
            as: 'category',
            attributes:['category']
          },{
            model: Publisher,
            as: 'publisher',
            attributes:['publisher']
          }],
           limit: size,
           offset: size * page
        })

        .then((result) => res.status(200).send(result))
        .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
      }
```

Comment: Sorry it didnt work. Maybe I have shared short info.
This is my repo. could you check it from this page ? Thank you.
Also I have problems with fetching data by using POST method

https://github.com/cevahir72/Library-App--Full-Stack/tree/main/backend